# How To Perform A Complete Overwrite of a git repository From Its Remote

Tags: git

I have been reading the various answers to my question, and the usual reset examples are not working. I have a git repository that is behind its remote. Resetting from the various examples I have read does not work. The remote is a true, accurate repository, and it can overwrite what I have.

How can I overwrite git completely and make sure the files on the remote and local -- it is the local that needs overwriting -- are the same?

Comment: The simplest thing to do, without more information about what you tried and how it failed, would be to just clone the remote repository again, deleting the old local repository once you verify your new clone has everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just throw away the existing local git repo and performing a fresh clone.

You could also do:

```
git fetch origin --all
git switch main
git reset --hard origin/main
```

Where you substitute `origin` with the name of your remote and `main` with whatever branch you want to reset to it's current equivalent on the remote.

Comment: Probably due to my version of git, a lot of your instructions would not work. I cloned the good repo. All is well.